# Continual ping in Packet Tracer

Tags: ping, packet-tracer

I would like to test my network with continuous ping in packet tracer.

When I use for example: `ping 192.168.4.100 -t`

Command line says `Invalid command`

I´m trying to ping from Laptop command line in packet tracer.

Are there other ways to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -t has to go before the address, like this:

```
ping -t 192.168.4.100
```